# Typescript - Encapsulating module/classes so it's not accessible from the browser

Tags: typescript

I'm looking for a way to write my TypeScript classes in a way that I could provide only what I want to provide to the browser (global scope), basically something like this:

`myModule.Api`

Where `Api` would contain some `public` functions that could be executed from the browser, but relaying on other functions that would be written is other classes within the same module or sub-modules.

I need that these classes could use each other, but wouldn't be usable from the browser global scope, only through the `Api`.

What's the way to go with that? I couldn't figure out how to reuse classes from other classes without exposing them to the browser directly using `export` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but wouldn't be usable from the browser

If you want something to transcend file boundaries you will need to `export` it from the file.

However if you keep it all on a single file then you don't need to use `export`.

```
module myModule.Api{
    var notExported = 0;
    export function exported(){
        return notExported + 1;
    }
}
```

I would like to point out that *when using external modules* each file is its own module and not exported to the browser i.e. `window` : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0

Comment: It is possible in JS to have a lot of code encapsulated in a function which isn't usable on the browser global scope, and only export what I want. Isn't possible in TS?

Comment: Yes. TS is just JS with added compile time type checks

Comment: So, the only solution would be to wrap the whole code into a scope while I conct it into a single file? I don't see any other solution for the moment. If I want to encapsulate the whole logic but using my classes from each other I will need to put all of them into a private scope so it's not globally accessible from the browser, then I'll need to manage what I expose globally.